# AngularJS - see tracing info on matching routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to enable detailed tracing information in AngularJS so I can see if my routes are matched correctly?

Comment: You can use ABatarang extension of chrome for tracing angularJS.

Comment: I tried that, but I don't see any AngularJS specific tracing, only my own log statements. Is there any trace level that must be configured?